# shows error stating no resource found that matches with the windowActionBarOverlay (android/res/styles.xml file)

Tags: android

```
         <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
```

I have used both method for action  bar overlay. It shows "error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowActionBarOverlay'."

Comment: Please provide more of your code and more information so we can help you.

Answer (score 2):

you need to separate styles.xml in res/values-v11 to support the same functionality in android 3.0 and up. add following parameter in that one

```
<item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
```

for below 3.0 you might need to clear up lint errors and run with the same style as you suggested

```
<item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
```